# Best way to create a page layout like this? Examples given!

Tags: jquery, page-layout, sharepoint-server

[image]I'm looking to make our main SharePoint 2013 page similar to that of t.msn.com.

Below are some screenshots.

Any ideas or recommendations will be much appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 1):

You should use basic html, css for creating the page layout. You should also need to know that how many category like: news, sports.. will be displayed? In which a category you can put the publishing fields for the category title, the images, and the content. Try to using div element for responsive web design.
Here's an simple ex:

```
<div class="mod-cat-wrapper">
   <div class="mod-cat-title">
       <SharePointWebControls:TextField  FieldName="CategoryTitle"  runat="server" />
   </div>
   <div class="mod-cat-content">
      <div class="mod-cat-header-image">
       <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="ImageField" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" runat="server"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mod-cat-header-title>
             <SharePointWebControls:TextField  FieldName="FieldId"  runat="server" />
      </div>
      <div class="mode-cat-main-content">
      <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="FieldId" runat="server" ></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After that you try make your css for the UI you want to be.